# Can a splash screen image be inserted at build time (in iOS / Android)

Tags: android, ios, xcode, firebase, splash-screen

We are a dev shop building an app using Ionic 5 with Cordova / Capacitor.  We currently have a generic splash screen and we simply change the image for every new client, but my understanding is this can only be done at build time.

If you look at the below screen shot, you can see that our icon is 'baked' into the app via Xcode.  Can this be added at run time?  We use Firebase to house all our information (including the icons), and it would be nice if the splash screen image could also be pulled from Firebase and used at build time.

[image]

The same concept exists for Android as well.  It is baked into the Android app as well.  Can this also be configured at run time.

[image]

Comment: Launch images and icons are included in the signed bundle.  They can't be changed at runtime.  You could have a blank or generic in-built launch image and have your first actual app screen be your launch screen.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Honestly, I kind of expected this.  I'll find another path

Comment: This is not possible to replace the icons and splash at build time. 
what I am doing is replace all the icons and splash before build using shell script. I have a whitelabel app and generating build through Jenkins.

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a new target for the new client?